# jqGrid display enum as string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I'm attempting to use the ASP.Net MVC version of jqGrid to display a simple data grid. One of the columns in my grid is an Enum and jqGrid is displaying is as an int whereas I want to display it as a string. How can I get jqGrid to display it as a string?

```
new JQGridColumn { DataField = "ApprovalStatus", 
     DataType = typeof(ApplicationStatusTypes),
     Editable = false,
     Width = 200},

public enum ApplicationStatusTypes
{
    Unassessed = 0,
    AssessmentInProgress = 1,
    RequirementsNotMet = 2,
    RequirementsPartiallyMet = 3,
    RequirementsMet = 4,
    Approved = 5
}
```

When the jqGrid is rendered the ApprovalStatus column shows up as an int instead of a string. I've tried messing around with DataFormatString on the column but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I see that this is an old question, but for any lost soul, that will come here.

First step is to set a `SetFormatter(Formatters.Select)` for the column used for displaying an enum.

But then you need to provide a list of enum mappings. jqGrid expects them to be provided as a string in format of *enumValue1:enumName1;enumValue2:enumName2* directly to `.SetEditOptions(new EditOptions { Value = ... })` - unfortunately the API naming convention is broken here.

The string generation itself is pretty straightforward and can be generalized to the following expression:

```
string.Join(";", Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)).Zip(Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<int>(), (text, val) => val.ToString() + ":" + text));
```

, where `T` is generic parameter being an enum type.